# Listing Directories in PHP

Tags: php, iframe

I have an < iframe > and when I "click" to one of the files .html that I show with this list it was appearing in this < iframe >. How  can I do that?
I need to change the src that has the < iframe >. Now the only thing that it does is to open to a new page. Thank you.

```
<iframe id="probando" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" scrolling="auto" height="700" width="800" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="probando"></iframe>
```

Since I can do that it changes the src that has the  giving click.  the only thing that it does is to open to a new . Thank you.
This is my code.

```
$directorioInicial = "./";    
$rep = opendir($directorioInicial);     
while ($arc = readdir($rep)) {       

if ($arc != '..' && $arc != '.' && $arc != '') {

    echo "<a href=" . $directorioInicial . "/" . $arc . " target='_blank'>" . $arc . "</a><br />";  
}
}
closedir($rep);      
clearstatcache();
```

Comment: Try to reformulate the question, some things get lost in translation ;)

Comment: Do you just want to know how to list all files in a folder? You can call [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) once like `$files = glob("*");`

Comment: I need to show in my < iframe > the new .html that I was "click" on my list :(

Comment: Iframes a thing of the past are they not?

Comment: @EvanCarslake No, should they? It still have many use cases, even in 2015 ;)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, i think you need to change the target of the link to "_self" instead of _blank. 
See [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/qt/target-links-iframes-and-frames.htm) for more info

Comment: Nice link, But what I need it's to show the file that I "clicked" on my iframe. I think I give to change the src attribute of my frame or something like that. But I dont know how...

Comment: Ahh, your links are outside your iframe and you like to open them within your iframe onclick? This will do: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

Comment: Yep its similar  but what I need its to put any file.html not pre-definited files or directions... I mean someone file that previusly was save in the designed folder